# Xcode project always throws SIGTRAP?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, exception

This might be a somewhat obscure or project specific question, but my project is throwing a SIGTRAP for every exception that is encountered.  I've never seen this before, and now it is throwing it every time there is a problem with my code and it does nothing to help me debug it.  In my other class that is similar I will get an index out of bounds exception, but in this class it's just SIGTRAP and I have to turn on exception breakpoints to see where the error is.  I'm not good with debugging this kind of thing, but here's some of the info that is presented, let me know if anything else would be helpful.

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__kill:
0x96f283b0:  movl   $786469, %eax
0x96f283b5:  calll  0x96f2a4c2                ; _sysenter_trap
0x96f283ba:  jae    0x96f283ca                ; __kill + 26
0x96f283bc:  calll  0x96f283c1                ; __kill + 17
0x96f283c1:  popl   %edx
0x96f283c2:  movl   27739(%edx), %edx
0x96f283c8:  jmpl   *%edx
0x96f283ca:  ret    
0x96f283cb:  nop
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You answered it yourself, enable exception breakpoint and check the stack trace - what else do you need?

Comment: I just don't understand why an index out of bounds is throwing a SIGTRAP.  In my other projects it just says index out of bounds exception and I don't need exception breakpoints.

Comment: Yes you do need an exception breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error shows that you are accessing index which is not accessible.
You must have problem in your loop,check conditions and loops and clean the project..
Good Luck !!